# Does this linear combination of vector norms describe a convex set?

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces, conic-sections, surfaces, convex-geometry

Consider the surface identified by the following implicit equation
\begin{equation}
|\vec{x}|+|\vec{y}|-|\vec{z}|-|\vec{x}+\vec{y}-\vec{z}|=0,
\end{equation}
with $(\vec{x},\vec{y},\vec{z})\in\mathbb{R}^{3N}$ and $|\cdot |$ being the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^N$.
Is such a surface convex in $\mathbb{R}^{3N}$? Are there some regions of $\mathbb{R}^{3N}$ in which the restriction of the surface to the region is convex?. Observe that this surface can be obtained by intersecting the following cones:
\begin{align}
t_x&=|\vec{x}|, \quad t_y=|\vec{y}|, \\
t_z&=|\vec{z}|, \quad t_x+t_y-t_z=|\vec{x}+\vec{y}-\vec{z}|,
\end{align}
where now $(t_x,\vec{x},t_y,\vec{y}, t_z, \vec{z})\in \mathbb{R}^{3(N+1)}$.

Comment: This is the raw text of your homework. What is your work on the subject ? Have you at least studied the case $N=1$ by considering what happens in the 8 octants ?

Comment: I promise it's not the "raw text" of my homework :). These surfaces arise very naturally from properties of certain integrals in particle physics. I would really love for these surfaces to be convex everywhere in $\mathbb{R}^{3N}$, but my hunch is that they are not. So that's where my second question (regarding possible "convex sectors") comes from.  In any case, for $N=1$ and restricting to the octants these become linear relations, so they are trivially convex (correct me if I'm wrong). I'm interested in knowing if the same happens for $N>1$ and how to show convexity.

Comment: Your text was so well written that I thought it was a HW...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that the case $N=1$ is "trivially convex".

I'm sorry but I don't agree at all.

I have been computing by hand at first, working at the elimination of the different absolute values, octant by octant, obtaining, as you say, one linear relationships, but not relationships with inequalities. Therefore the 3D set is a surface (S), not a volume, made of 8 planar sectors (6 with a 90° opening, 2 with a 60° opening) assembled as a double umbrella (symmetrical with respect to the origin).

Therefore (S) is not eligible to be a convex set: the midpoint of 2 points of (S), is - most often - not in (S). If you restrict (S) to one of these 8  planar sectors, you have a convex set...

Then, I have written a Matlab program (see below) that has given this, confirming my computations:

[image]

```
clear all;close all;hold on;axis equal
f= @(x,y,z)(abs(x)+abs(y)-abs(z)-abs(x+y-z));
a=3; N = 100; W=4;L='linewidth';
plot3([-a,a],[0,0],[0,0],L,W); % x axis
plot3([0,0],[-a,a],[0,0],L,W);
plot3([0,0],[0,0],[-a,a],L,W);
plot3([a,-a],[0,0],[a,-a],L,W);
plot3([0,0],[a,-a],[a,-a],L,W);
u = linspace(-a,a, N);
[X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(u, u, u);
D = f(X, Y, Z);
isosurface(X,Y,Z,D,-0.01);% levelset of f for value v=-0.01
view([-126,12])
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
zlabel('z');
```

I f we consider now the region defined by $|x|+|y|-|z|-|x+y-z|<0$ we will get the interior of the umbrellas, with "nice level sets". See for example below the level set

$$|x|+|y|-|z|-|x+y-z|=-0.5$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but to go back to my statement of trivial convexity, I was referring to the restriction to the octants, so that the set identified by the implicit equation when restricting to the octants is convex. That is one can divide the embedding space in sectors such that the restriction of the surface described by the implicit equation to those sectors is convex (in the $N=1$ case, they would be portions of a hyperplane, hence my statement of convexity being trivial on the restrictions).

Comment: In any case, your answer basically settles my questions, in that it provides a negative answer to the first one, and provides me with an idea on how to answer the second

Comment: It is interesting to see that replacing your equality by the inequality $|x|+|y|-|z|-|x+y-z|<0$, one gets the interior of the umbrellas (two prismatic volumes which, individually, are convex).

Comment: See the figure I just added.

Comment: yes that's quite interesting. It kind of looks like the two sheets of an hyperboloid or cone oriented along the axis $x+y-z=0$ (one sheet of an hyperboloid generically has implicit equation $|\vec{x}|-|\vec{x}+\vec{v}|=a$, with $\vec{v}$ and $a$ fixed), which do separately identify convex volumes. Hopefully this still holds for $N>1$, that would be great :).

Comment: Interesting connection...

Comment: Considering the level set $(|x|+|y|-|z|-|x+y-z|)(|x|+|y|+|z|+|x+y-z|)=-0.5$, I just verified that one indeed gets a surface that "looks like" an $H_2$, an hyperboloid **with two sheets** (the second factor has a "smoothing" effect), but in fact made of pieces of different $H_2$s.